# ROS2 binary release without showing source code

Tags: ros2, release, binary

My team and I are implementing [rmw](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Concepts/Advanced/About-Middleware-Implementations.html) implementation for our DDS product. We want to upload our rmw implementation to the community. However, it is a challenge for us to upload the source code of the rmw implementation because of our company policies.

Is there a way for us to upload binary packages only?

This [link](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Releasing/First-Time-Release.html) seems to explain binary release with source code included.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic wrt the question, but I suggest to first announce this on the [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/), explain how your RMW implementation differs from the existing implementations and in which way it could be interesting to the community, and only spend the time to release it binary-only _if_ there is enough interest.